# FME: Feature Name when feature is empty

Tags: fme-form, fme-transformer

I am exporting all the feature names and the count for each in an Excel Sheet.

1. Enable the feature names in all features
   [image]

Custom Transformer:

2. StatisticCalculator --> Count
3. StatisticCalculator --> fme_feature_type
4. FeatureMerger --> Merge Count and fm_feature_type

Main:

5. Writer .xlsxw

This works fine for the features that have at least 1 field.
How can I retrieve the names of the features that are empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a FeatureReader (initiated by a Creator) and use the Schema feature from the  outputport. With Excel as format, each sheet is a Schema Feature.

As an alternative you can also use the classic "Schema (Any Format)" reader.

Comment: Thank you @nielsgerrits :) I used the Schema (Any Format) Reader